# Buttons are disappearing when orientation is horizontal

Tags: java, android

I have a weired problem - I see buttons when the orientation is set to vertical - but they disappear when set to horizontal. They are also don't have width, height or bottom. they just doesn't exist. All because of the horizontal. What can I do?
Here is the code:

```
private void addViews(int addAnotherColor)
{
    if (buttonView != null)
    {
        buttonView.removeAllViews();
    }

    buttonView = new LinearLayout(this);
    buttonView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    buttonView.setId(3);

    try
    {
        InputStream deleteImage = getAssets().open("delete.bmp");
        InputStream fewColorsImage = getAssets().open("fewColors.bmp");
        InputStream doNotHillImage = getAssets().open("doNotHill.bmp");
        InputStream pauseImage = getAssets().open("pause.bmp");
        InputStream elusiveColor = getAssets().open("elusive.bmp");

        fewColors.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fewColorsImage));
        elusive.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(elusiveColor));
        hillIt.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(doNotHillImage));
        delete.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(deleteImage));
        pause.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(pauseImage));

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    buttonView.addView(pause, 70, 60);  
    buttonView.addView(delete, 100, 60);
    buttonView.addView(randomColor, 150, 60);
    buttonView.addView(fewColors, 192, 60);
    buttonView.addView(hillIt, 120, 60);
    buttonView.addView(elusive, 150, 60);

    menuView.addView(buttonView);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set the LinearLayout to Horizontal, all will probably be on one line, setting most of the stuff you add way out of the screens right side.

You would probably want to add another LinearLayout inside the one you already have to add these buttons to, which I guess you want on the same row.

Comment: But I don't see anything...None of the buttons appear, not just some... You suggest that maybe some will appear - it doesn't...